# .htaccess require ip not working

Tags: windows, apache-2.4

I set up an `Apache 2.4` web server under Win 10 and I want to restrict access to Canadians only as the information is only relevant to them.

I have `.htaccess` in htdocs directory as follows with a list of acceptable Canadian IP addresses and of course my local `192.168.x.x` network as follows:

```
# -------------------------------------------------------
# Free IP2Location Firewall List by Country
# Source: https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker
# Last Generated: 25 Jul 2018 20:30:40 GMT
# [Important] Please update this list every month
# -------------------------------------------------------
<RequireAny>
    Require 192.168.
    Require ip 2.17.218.0/24
    Require ip 4.14.243.128/27
    ....
    Require ip 69.90.33.64/26
</RequireAny>
```

However, I am getting enters in the access log from countries outside of Canada - here are some examples.

```
Hong Kong
202.88.97.132 - "GET /phpmyadmin/main.php HTTP/1.0" 404 217
202.88.97.132 - "GET /db/main.php HTTP/1.0" 404 209
202.88.97.132 - "GET /web/main.php HTTP/1.0" 404 210

United Kingdom
132.232.15.93 - "GET /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 404 205
132.232.15.93 - "POST /wuwu11.php HTTP/1.1" 404 208

Lebanon
178.135.60.86 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 57418
```

How do I completely restrict access to Apache from countries outside of Canada?

Comment: Are those IPs **in** your `<RequireAny>` block somewhere? Maybe the "Free IP2Location Firewall List by Country" just isn't a very good list? Have you tested with your own IP in the block list to make sure it's working at all? What about a Canadian who's in the UK for vacation but wants your info? Why bother with this at all?

Comment: Thanks - not really worried about Canadians who are out of the country as they don't take their backyard ponds with them. My site is about native (local) water plants

Why bother? I have running a very small machine - little ram and little CPU power . To many Asian - primarily Chinese - hackers trying to crack into the system. 

The IPs in the <RequireAny> are Canadian IPs  and .htaccess is located in htdocs directory

What solution do you recommend?

Comment: I'd put CloudFlare in place and stop worrying about it at that point.

Comment: Too much work for a 1 page website with a couple dozen pdf files. Thanks

Comment: The last time I set up CloudFlare it took about 15 minutes.¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: BTW - I did check the unwanted IPs that got through and they are not in the required list

Comment: Try banning your own IP as a test. That'll at least tell if you if your configuration is doing *anything*.